# T-Tap Connector for 12/2 Low Voltage Landscape Lighting

Tags: lighting, low-voltage

I'm looking to install wiring for some outdoor post lights. More specifically, I will have an approximately 150' run of low voltage wiring with 9 evenly spaced T intersections. Each T will have an individual run of about 6' to an [outdoor light](https://www.lampsplus.com/products/casa-sorrento-16-and-three-quarter-inch-high-black-post-mount-light__32983.html) on a concrete block column.

I plan to use [dimmable 60 watt (equivalent)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HB7CX3N) LED bulbs (so 7 actual watts) and given the length of the run and the number of lights, I was thinking of using [12/2 direct burial cable](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-250-ft-12-2-Gray-Solid-CU-UF-B-W-G-Wire-13055955/202316281).

To make my life easier, I'm hoping to find a t-tap connector for each of the light runs.

Questions:

- Is this [3M™ Scotchlok™ Moisture Guard Connector](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/p/d/b00014126/?preselect=7579096%208778676) what I want to be using at the intersections? Are there other alternatives?
- Do you think 12/2 gauge wire is overkill for application?
- Any guidance on transformer specs to ensure I can adequately power all 9 lights is also appreciated

Thank you

Comment: You need to decide what bulb wattage you want to use. All decisions are driven by that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not dodging the Q, but what I do know is the light fixtures are rated up to 100 watts.

These lights are mostly for ambience and moderate visibility, not looking for super bright.  Was also expecting to get a dimmable transformer and bulbs.

Shooting from the hip, I'd say 60 watts (~800 lumens) would suffice.

Comment: You know, they make landscape wire specific-for-task, which is a fraction of the cost of UF-B.  You need to be clear on your units, watts vs lumens.  Lumens is the actual light output e.g. 800lm is reasonable for a landscape light.  Watts is the energy they require, and that decides the wire size.  An 800lm light would be 60 watts in obsolete incandescent.  Do you want to size the wire so you can use incandescents, or are you all-in for LED? Also what voltage are we talking about?

Comment: I appreciate the discussion. Learning as I go. So I'd say the LED bulbs will be 60 watt equivalent, so would be 8-10 watts actual. My belief is that these type of bulb will produce about 800 lumens.

Example: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08L36HXY3/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_SGHV5GXPZMVTMZPEAV64

Comment: Those are 120V AC, not low voltage DC.

Comment: For that much wattage at that distance, you could have significant (like 20%) voltage drop by the end of the line at 12V even with 12Ga wire. You’d want to look for a 24V system or maybe even 48.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the wattage? many times the ratings are now obsolete as there were intended for incandescent bulbs, not the highly more efficient, LEDs.   With incandescent low voltage, you had to be super careful about voltage drop and run large GA cables.  With LED you have to add up the number of ACTUAL watts being used by each fixture, not the incandescent equivalent. 60 watts for an LED bulb seems really high. Anyway, double check the actual wattage per bulb/fixture add them up and there are charts online that will guide you in selecting the right wire gauge.  Wrapping this up, I'll just say bigger is usually better, when in doubt.

Comment: I appreciate the discussion. Learning as I go. So I'd say the LED bulbs will be 60 watt equivalent, so would be 8-10 watts actual.

Comment: This feels much more like a comment than an answer, George.